# How to develop two separate feature branches with Git

Tags: git

I am starting an app development using Git, with main development in the master branch.  I want to create a branch for a certain limited feature set and maintain both branches permanently.  They will never be merged, but sometimes I might find bugs that need to be fixed in both.  Is Git capable of managing this, and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, Git can handle this, but the bigger question here might be why you want a long life branch which will never be merged.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is an often used strategy when dealing with multiple maintained versions where the newer ones introduce API breaking features. For example, you will have the "v_1.0" branch forked from master.

Comment: Customers of v1 are entitled to free updates within the v1 branch for bug fixes and minor features, but major features go in v2 and require a new purchase.

Comment: It's a complex and high maintenance strategy.  Changes must be merged between branches,  but the diff can never be empty.   Coupling repo versioning to api or even distributable version incurs inflexibility by  connecting orthogonal characteristics.   If you must support different versions,  prefer to express them in code concurrently so the various versions can managed in the same codebase.  Build as many artifacts as you need to.   Such price per version models are becoming increasingly rare

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategy is cherry picking the commits you want to integrate. This will create a commit on top of the current branch from the commit which change you want to integrate but it will not have the other branch as a parent (which is what you are asking).

Assuming that you have a clean repository on the head of the branch you want to integrate the changes into:

```sh
git checkout master # master is the branch you want to integrate your changes into
git status # should be clean
git cherry-pick 1234fe 15dead # the commits you want to cherry pick
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick for more options.

If you want to keep track of what commit were integrated, you can also make empty merge commits. Assuming you are on the master branch:

```sh
git merge forked-branch -s ours
```

But personally I find that it pollutes the history more than anything else.

That being said, ask yourself, do you really want this? Having to solve more and more merge conflicts as time go on? Having more and more versions shackling the developers down knowing they will have to deal with this later down the line and potentially demoralizing them when making much needed architectural improvements that move and rename files and such?

As other comments pointed out, less and less companies do this and for good reasons. If this breaks your API, create another one that lives in parallel. If there are features certain clients must pay then you can implement features toggle.